# JPA/Hibernate: Annotations for already created table

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have two tables (already created), say Person and Address with following schemas:

```
create table Person (
    `id` int(11) not null auto_increment,
    `name` varchar(255) default null,
    primary key(`id`)
)

create table Address (
    `id` int(11) not null,
    `city` varchar(255) default null,
    primary key (`id`),
    constraint foreign key (`id`) references `Person`(`id`)
)
```

Now, which annotations should I use in the code?

The skeletons of both the classes are:

```
class Person {
    @Id @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name="id")
    int id;
    String name;

    Address address;
}

class Address {
    int id;
}
```

I need to add annotations for *address* field in **Person** class and *id* field of **Address** class.

Comment: Is it correct that the person id and the address id will always be the same?

Comment: Yes. Actually Person and Address has one-to-one relationship.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want to use [@MapsId](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/index.html?javax/persistence/package-summary.html).

```
@Entity
class Person {
   @Id 
   @GeneratedValue
   int id;

   String name;

   @OneToOne 
   @MapsId
   Address address;
}

@Entity
class Address {
    @Id
    int id;
}
```

Check out example 2 in the [@OneToOne](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/OneToOne.html) documentation.

Answer (score 1):

in Person.java

```
@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "id",nullable=false)
@ForeignKey(name = "fk_id")     
private Address address;
```

and in Address .java -

```
@OneToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "id", updatable = false, insertable = false, nullable=false)  
private Person id;    

@Column(name = "id", insertable = false, updatable = false, nullable=false)
private Integer id;
```

Comment: Thanks but I can't add Person field in the Address class.

Comment: here person stands for id. I have modified the example you can check this out again. here i have created 2 mapping for one column. One would return id and another would return Person object.

Answer (score 0):

```
 class Person {
   @Id @GeneratedValue
   @Column(name="id")
   int id;
   String name;

   @OneToOne
   @JoinColumn(name = "address_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
   Address address;
}

class Address {
    @id
    int id;
}
```

Comment: not sure this would work as there is no address_id column in the schema

Comment: We can have column name "address_id" for id field in Address class. Would it work?

Comment: @JoinColumn(name = "address_id", referencedColumnName = "id") means
address_id column in person table will reference the id column in address table but u need to create address_id column in person table.